# Does Bootstrap3 work with Firefox v25.0.1 and AngularJS? FireFox not displaying table

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, dom, html-table

I am running AngularJS 1.2.3 and Bootstrap3 to create a simple task list app.
The code and Bootstrap3 CSS works everywhere (IE11.x, Chrome v31.0.1650.63 m, Opera v18.0.1284.63), except FireFox 25.0.1

If I add the link to bootstrap3 via

```
<link href="3rdPartyLibs/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then when AngularJS ng-repeat runs to create the table rows then FireFox v25.0.1 does not render the table header or rows and display them to the user However, **if you look at the source, they are being created.**

Here's an image of the page and an image of the source:
**It should look like this:**
[image]

FireFox displays this **(notice there are no rows)**:
[image]

In FireFox, if I click the [Add New Task] button numerous times, it actually alters the DOM as I expect it to (adding rows to the table), but it doesn't display that to the user.  However, the source is altered -- rows are added to the table -- and the source looks like this:
[image]
**Referencing Bootstrap2 Makes It Work**

All I have to do to make it work is reference Bootstrap2 on my machine (i have both locally) by altering the link to : (notice there is no 3 in the bootstrap directory.

```
<link href="3rdPartyLibs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After I do that, it works in FireFox too and looks like:
[image]

Does bootstrap3 work in FireFox?  Is there some special initialization I have to do?
Is Bootstrap3 not ready for prime-time, or is it FireFox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Figured It Out While Attempting To Convert To Bootstrap2**

I decided to convert this thing to work with Bootstrap2 since that would mean all browsers would work.  While doing that I discovered that if I simply add a  wrapper to my table, then it fixes the problem.
Here's a **summary** of what I had and what I did:

***note:**If you see unclosed tags, that is bec. it's a summary, please don't try to tell me I need to close those tags.  It is valid HTML in the real thing.  thanks.*

**I had**

```
<html>
  <div>
     <button1>
     <button2>...
  </div>
  <table>
       <thead>
              <th> 
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="t in allTasks"
       </tbody>
  </table>
</html>
```

I simply wrapped my table in another **div** and now it works in FireFox.  Looks like this:

```
<html>
  <div>
     <button1>
     <button2>...
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
         <thead>
                <th> 
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="t in allTasks"
         </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

**Now it looks like it should in FireFox**
[image]